# Can I get the link for iTunes installation before releasing mt app?

Tags: iphone, release, itunes

I am in the middle of finalizing my website getting ready for the releasing of my iPhone app, now I am wondering if it's possible to get the link for iTunes installation earlier, even before it's officially approved by AppStore. Anyone tried that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Login into [iTunes Connect](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/WebObjects/iTunesConnect.woa) and go to Manage Your Apps
then click on the app you had uploaded and right click on View in App Store and go to Open Link in New tab...

By doing this you will get iTunes Link for your application..

Answer (score 3):

Absolutely.

1. Create the app in iTunes if you haven't already.
2. Go to the app page in iTunes.
3. On the main page for your app copy the link from "View in App Store"

Once it is approved that will be its URL.